# How to write a shell script to checkpoint a running process in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shell, process, restore, checkpoint

CRIU or any other checkpoint/restore command cannot be used. I need to be able to restore the process on a different system.

Answer (score 0):

That is what CRIU should be able to do. I mean create checkpoint and restore it at another machine. See CRIU documentation for container live migration:

> This is the use case from what the whole checkpoint/restore project
>   appeared. Container is checkpointed, then the image is copied on
>   another box, then restored. From the remote observer point of view the
>   container is just frozen for a while.

It is quite challenging to write an application that migrates a process to another machine. It would be necessary to recover process hierarchy, privileges, file descriptors, network connections, signals...

It is too many issues to describe in a single answer.